# How to align photos horizontally that was previously aligned vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm "converting" a responsive website and need help with aligning 3 images horizontally that was previously aligned vertically on mobile. I have read some StackOverflow posts, but can't find any solution that works for me.

Check out JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8dkgcyfq/1/

```
<section class="team">
  <div>
  <img src="img/lady.jpg">
  <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
  <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>

  <div>
  <img src="img/lady.jpg">
  <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
  <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>

  <div>
  <img src="img/lady.jpg">
  <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
  <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>
</section>

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .team img {
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  .team {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .team h2 {
    font-family: "Catamaran";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  .team h1 {
    font-family: "Catamaran";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }

  .team i {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

Need some help aligning these photos horizontally.

Comment: Images in the jsfiddle link are broken. Please don't use local paths/images in an example like that.

Comment: Replaced the images with placeholders

Comment: you might want to think of using some sort of grid system that can do this automatically for you, I use [gridle](https://gridle.org/demo/demo.html) as it comes with less guff than bootstrap.  If you do not want to install a grid system, then you just need to make media queries changing the width of the children from 100% to 33% at your desired breakpoint

Comment: Adding to what @Pete mentioned, CSS Flexbox could solve your problem as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I am practicing so I want to do this just by using HTML and CSS.

Comment: Ok so if you do this yourself, your rows want to be flex with flex-direction row and flex wrap wrap, then just start your child divs off at 100% adding in media queries to change the width as you size your browser up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comments, I would use flexbox and a mobile first approach meaning you should only need to change the width in your media query:

```css
/* put all default styleing outside media query */

.team {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

/* I always do mobile first then media query tablet and above */

.team > div {
  /* personally, I would give these divs a class instead of having to do a bare selector (the slowest of all element selectors) */
  width:100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .team > div {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="team">
  <div>
    <img src="img/lady.jpg">
    <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
    <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="img/lady.jpg">
    <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
    <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="img/lady.jpg">
    <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
    <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, got two solutions now :)

Comment: @KarimZ just noticed you have h2 before h1 - big accessibility no-no (headings should always be used in order unless finishing a section and going back up to a previous higher heading - https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings/

Comment: oh didn't know that. Thanks, will fix that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` on `.team` . On mobile ( so default ) you use `flex-direction : column` so the images are vertically one under the other.

In media query ( where you want to change them ) use `flex-direction: row`. This way the images ( divs ) will be on one row And style from there.

Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jyxs8kz/) or snippet below.

```css
.team {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .team img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .team {
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .team h2 {
    font-family: "Catamaran";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .team h1 {
    font-family: "Catamaran";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  .team i {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="team">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
    <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
    <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <h2>Navn Navnesen</h2>
    <h1>contact@gmail.com</h1>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```