# Is it possible to make a flex box with with % images instead of pixels?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I have the width of the images set to a % with `flex-wrap: wrap;`, flex wrap doesn't work. I can understand because the image stays proportional to the viewport. When I switch it to px it works.
Is there a way to keep it as a % to be fluid, but when the images get below a certain size it wraps?

I've tried using % and px. Flex wrap works for px but not %.

```
* {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
        box-sizing: border-box;}

    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: .5%;
        padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .flex-container > div {
        text-align: center;
        margin: .5%;
        width: 31%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:500px) {
        .column {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```
<div class="flex-container">

<div><img src="Images/Printing/Dinner Menus-01.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Banners" /></div>
<div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Posters" /></div>
<div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Poster" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use media queries to change the width so it wraps - [pretty similar to this question I just answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401219/how-to-align-photos-horizontally-that-was-previously-aligned-vertically/55401580#55401580)

Comment: the `.column` in your media query is not found in your html